# Displaying VBA SQL String Query as a datasheet on a form in MSAccess

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am having trouble trying to execute a SQL string within VBA to display a datasheet with criteria from a form. At the moment once the command button is pressed it doesn't seem to do anything because it returns no errors. My idea is to replicate an in built query that access creates as it returns the results in a datasheet.

My Code is below:

```vb
Private Sub cmdschcompliance_Click()
Dim sSQL As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strSql As String
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

If Me.lstsite.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please Select a Site:"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtschfrom.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Date From:"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtschto.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Date To:"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf IsNull(Me.TxtSchLetter.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Schedule Letter:"
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each varItem In Me.lstsite.ItemsSelected
    strCriteria = strCriteria & "[Qry_Union].[Site]='" & Me.lstsite.ItemData(varItem) & "' Or "
Next
If Right(strCriteria, 4) = " Or " Then strCriteria = "(" & Left(strCriteria, Len(strCriteria) - 4) & ")"


sSQL = "SELECT BFMA_TaskList.Task AS [Task No], [Task Group] & "" "" & [Task Details] AS [Task Detail], """" AS [USVF Compliance], """" AS [DIO Contract Compliance], """" AS [Other Compliance]" & _
"FROM [BFMA_TaskList] INNER JOIN [Qry_Union] ON [BFMA_TaskList].[Task] = [Qry_Union].[Task] " & _
"WHERE " & strCriteria & " AND [BFMA_TaskList].[Schedule]='" & Me![TxtSchLetter] & "' AND [Qry_Union].[Planned Date] Between #" & Format(Me![txtschfrom], "mm\/dd\/yy") & "# And #" & Format(Me![txtschto], "mm\/dd\/yy") & "#;"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("QrySchedComp")
Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow
qdf.SQL = sSQL


On Error Resume Next
'Delete the query if it already exists
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "QrySchedComp"

DoCmd.OpenQuery qdf.SQL, acViewNormal, acEdit

'release memory
qdf.Close
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

I am new to VBA and SQL so any information will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Make `QrySchedComp` a saved query. Don't create it on the fly and do not delete it. You can still use VBA to edit it's SQL before displaying it, if necessary.

Comment: Also, subject to SQL injection as written. Obligatory [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/327/). Get your immediate problem solved, then take a look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few main issues are present with your current setup:

1. The reason you do not see any errors is `On Error Resume Next` which tells compiler to continue to next line on any runtime error and does not inform user of any issue. You should be raising errors in an error handling process with `MsgBox`. See this [note](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm).
2. You cannot use an SQL `SELECT` string in [DoCmd.OpenQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-openquery-method-access) as you are attempting with:

   ```
   DoCmd.OpenQuery qdf.SQL, acViewNormal, acEdit
   ```

   You must use a saved query and reference its name in the command:

   ```
   DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedQuery", acViewNormal, acEdit
   ```
3. Continue to use QueryDef's `.SQL` property for dynamic SQL but be sure to release querydef to save changes prior to opening the datasheet view:

   ```vb
   sSQL = "..."

   Set db = CurrentDb
   Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("QrySchedComp")

   Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow
   qdf.SQL = sSQL

   ' RELEASE QUERYDEF TO SAVE CHANGES
   Set qdf = Nothing
   Set db = Nothing

   DoCmd.OpenQuery "QrySchedComp", acViewNormal, acEdit
   ```

---

With that said, consider parameterized queries using [QueryDef parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx) that avoids quote/pound sign enclosures and string concatenation, and abstracts data from code, not to mention it safely avoids SQL injection, a potential issue of user input.

And since you are iterating across a multiple select listbox, consider using a temp table that replicates structure of current query. This might even yield better performance for your users as you avoid the `JOIN` on a `UNION` query in datasheet for any filtering and searching needs.

**SQL**

Make-table action query to create temp table to be run only **once** to replicate structure:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 * INTO tmpSchedComp FROM QrySchedComp
```

Save action query only **once** as a stored, parameterized query *(no data)*:

```sql
PARAMETERS SiteParam Text(255), ScheduleParam Text(255), 
           DateStartParam Datetime, DateEndParam Datetime;
INSERT INTO tmpSchedComp ([Task No], [Task Detail], [USVF Compliance], 
                          [DIO Contract Compliance],  [Other Compliance])
SELECT BFMA_TaskList.Task AS [Task No], [Task Group] & '' & [Task Details] AS [Task Detail], 
       '' AS [USVF Compliance], '' AS [DIO Contract Compliance], '' AS [Other Compliance]
FROM [BFMA_TaskList] 
INNER JOIN [Qry_Union] ON [BFMA_TaskList].[Task] = [Qry_Union].[Task] 
WHERE [Qry_Union].[Site] = [SiteParam] AND [BFMA_TaskList].[Schedule] = [ScheduleParam]
  AND [Qry_Union].[Planned Date] BETWEEN [DateStartParam] AND [DateEndParam]
```

**VBA** *(run loop without `OR` concatenation to append records per site, then open temp table)*

```vb
...
Set db = CurrentDb
' CLEAN OUT TEMP TABLE
db.Execute "DELETE FROM tmpSchedComp", dbFailOnError

' INITIALIZE QUERYDEF (ACTION QUERY)
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("AppnSchedComp")

' POPULATE TEMP TABLE
For Each varItem In Me.lstsite.ItemsSelected      
   ' BIND VALUES TO PARAMETERS
    qdf!SiteParam = Me.lstsite.ItemData(varItem)
    qdf!ScheduleParam = Me![TxtSchLetter]
    qdf!DateStartParam = Me![txtschfrom]
    qdf!DateEndParam = Me![txtschto]

    ' EXECUTE ACTION
    qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
Next varItem

Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

DoCmd.OpenTable "tmpSchedComp", acViewNormal
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("QrySchedComp")
```

Creates a query in access called QrySchedComp, unless you are deleting that at some other point in your code you will start generating errors after the first time you run this method because it will try to create another instance of the query with the same name.

You can either modify its SQL statement using VBA as SunKnight0 suggested or if this is only meant to be run once, or you are deleting it somewhere else, then you can just link the query to the datasheet.

If you don't want to do that, you can instead set a temporary query to the datasheet's recordset using:

```
NameOfYourForm.recordset = db.CreateQueryDef("")
```

I think you will also need to enable the VBA code for the form to make this work.  I can't remember if this was dependent on that or not.  Just change the Has Module option to Yes to do that.